# how to select those entries who are join partner to every entry from another?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following schema: (asterisk means key attribute)

```
person(name*)
prototype(id*, name->person)
upgrade(old*->prototype, new*->prototype)
```

I made sub queries:

```
WITH johnny AS(
    SELECT id FROM prototype WHERE name = 'john')

WITH X AS(
    SELECT prot.name AS upgrader, j.id AS oldStuff  FROM upgrade AS u
    JOIN johnny AS j ON u.old = j.id
    JOIN prototype AS prot ON prot.id = u.new
    )
```

The goal is to find the names of people who made an upgraded/new prototype to EVERY prototype of a person named ´johnny', but i don't know how

Maybe you could help me out

Person:

```
name --- 
john 
karl 
peter
```

Prototype:

```
id|name --- 
1|john 
2|john 
3|john 
4|karl 
5|karl 
6|karl 
7|karl 
8|peter
```

upgrade:

```
old|new --- 
1|4 
2|5 
3|6 
7|8
```

desired result: karl

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Person:
name
---
john
karl
peter

Prototype:
id|name
---
1|john
2|john
3|john
4|karl
5|karl
6|karl
7|karl
8|peter

upgrade:
old|new
---
1|4
2|5
3|6
7|8

desired result:
karl

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why this has been closed. So I'm posting my answer here in the comments: You want to select all those "to names" that have as many "from join" entries as there are "john prototypes". (Hope this makes sense :-) The query: `select x.name from upgrade u join prototype x on x.id = u.new where u.old in (select id from prototype where name = 'john') group by x.name having count(*) = (select count(*) from prototype where name = 'john');`

Comment: Thanks for your input, but they might be right. I didnt specify the requirements precise enough..
The number does not matter, because if someone produces 2 upgrades to the same prototype and every other (so 4 upgrades to 3 prototypes) his name s hould be in the result set and if somebody produces 3 upgrades to only one of the 3 prototypes john produced, it should not be included. The relevant part is that EVERY id from my johnny subquery appears atleast once within the x subquery beneath the name of the "upgrader" whose name i want to have as a result if this condition is true.

Comment: beneath = in the same row

Comment: Then use `group_concat` instead of `count`: `select x.name from upgrade u join prototype x on x.id = u.new where u.old in (select id from prototype where name = 'john') group by x.name having group_concat(distinct u.old order by u.old) = (select group_concat(id order by id) from prototype where name = 'john');`

Comment: As to multiple upgrades on the same prototype: Why don't you just update your request with this information? Edit it and show an example with karl matching the requirement and mike only getting close. It can't be so difficult to come up with an example that explains the situation.